# Android Studio Java fab is in red color

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, mobile-application

I am new to Android Studio. I am following a video tutorial to make a TODO app. I was following this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpHVtSvdeOI
At 14:44, I typed "fab", and it is in red color. I tried "Show Context Actions" but nothing works. I followed the exact same steps that he did but I still have that problem.
Here is the code:

```
package com.example.medicinereminder;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.medicinereminder.Utils.DataBaseHelper;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

public class ReminderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private DataBaseHelper myDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);

        mRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        myDB = new DataBaseHelper(ReminderActivity.this);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And a screenshot

[image: Code]

Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ReminderActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medicine Reminder List"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.042" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/plus"
        android:text="Button"
        app:backgroundTint="#00FDFDFD"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.977"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.957" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please show the XML file related to that activity?

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 I just edit the question. You can see the XML code now

Comment: Ok, notice that there is not any element with "android:id="@+id/fab"". That's why the word is in red. If you're following a video, check the part where he defines the XML file, or if that button is in other XML file.

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 yes I found that part in the video. Thanks for your help. Another mistake that I found was that I declared FloatingActionButton, I could just declare button. In the video, he added materials in dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Floating Action button(dependency needed) then there must be floating action in XML
then only this line work

```
private FloatingActionButton fab;
```

And use this instead of Button in XML

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
    android:contentDescription="@string/submit"
    android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

But if you are using the normal button in XML
and you are giving

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
```

so you need to declare like this

```
private Button btnadd;
```

then to read that button you can do

```
btnadd = findViewById(R.id.addtn);
```

For better understand refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button)